# What can my moons be made of?

Tags: moons, astrophysics

So I asked a question before about having two moons. A wise patron suggested my moon be made out of something like blown glass, in order to have a big bright moon that isn't too dense. That has me thinking...
Would that make them glow, all the way through, so there would necessarily be a dark side? Could it be gemstones, to make it even brighter? I've heard there are planets made of "precious" minerals.

Comment: So, what are you trying to achieve? Depending on it, cheese is another possible option.

Comment: @Alexander: https://what-if.xkcd.com/4 Obligatory XKCD (apparently in-line hyperlinking is broken in comments..)

Comment: If you're trying to achieve a glowing moon, the approach you're thinking of isn't going to (realistically) work. You're much better off simply making it hot (say due to recent heavy bombardment or very abundant radionuclides) and have the surface glow via incandescence.

Answer (score 5):

### Carbon planets

We typically expect a moon's composition to reflect the part of the protoplanetary disk it came from. If it's orbiting a planet close to the star, we'd expect it to be composed largely of silicates, like Earth or the Moon. If it orbits farther out, it would be reasonable to expect there to be plenty of volatiles, too, like water ice or ammonia. Gaseous exomoons are less likely, of course, as the bodies are almost certainly too small to retain gaseous envelopes.

The more exotic compositions you're indicating are reminiscent of several particular [carbon planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_planet). These are planets originating in a system with an unusually high amount of carbon, including possible carbon-to-oxygen ratios greater than one (see [Delgado Mena et al. 2010](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/725/2/2349)). Some of these planets contain so much carbon that graphite or diamond may be their primary constituents - hence the popular term "diamond planet". The name has been applied to several carbon-rich exoplanets:

- [55 Cancri e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/55_Cancri_e), about 8 Earth masses
- [WASP-12b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WASP-12b), about 1.4 Jupiter masses

I should note that the composition of these planets is *not* totally certain, and some groups have argued the graphite is the primary constituent, not diamond ([Teske et al. 2013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.6032)).

Why am I talking about planets, though, when you asked about moons? Well, as I said before, the composition of a moon should reflect the composition of the protoplanetary disk it came from. If planets with significant diamond content can form, then so too could moons.

### Structure

We don't have detailed models of carbon moons, though work has been done on the structure of carbon planets of varying masses ([Hakim et al. 2019](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02064)). It seems that a low-mass carbon planet would likely have the following structure, due to stratification:

- An iron inner core depleted of sulfur
- An iron outer core *with* sulfur
- A substantially larger mantle made of silicates
- An outer layer of carbon, likely graphite.

Some worlds will have a layer of diamond underneath the graphite; moreover, convection may transport some of that diamond into the mantle, enriching it with diamond.

The only way you can produce a planet that is *entirely* diamond would be if there were no silicates, iron, or similar compounds or elements in the protoplanetary nebula, and that's just not likely.

Comment: Doesn’t the albedo of carbon range from utterly reflective down to utterly black dependant on structure? Would the randomisation of structure make the average planetary albedo low (though the surface might be sparkly and fabulous)?

Comment: @JoeBloggs Yes, presumably, the planet would be quite dark because of the surface graphite, regardless of the diamond below.

Answer (score 3):

Having a moon made entirely out of glass, however infeasible it is, would still have sufficient impurities to make it opaque. So no, it would not really allow light to pass all the way through. Also, over millions of years, meteor bombardment and material accretion will either cause cracking and fissures to obscure clarity.

Depending on the local stellar mineral make up will dictate the concentration of precious materials, however, the more "precious material" available in the initial formation of the planetary system would make it less precious. But basing it on average cosmic material availability, your world would probably be made up of mostly water, silicon, carbon, iron and such other common elements.

Gemstones are typically made by high heat and pressure, so if your moon was the remnant core of an old destroyed world, then it may have an abundance of gemstones such as diamond or ruby, made from carbon and aluminum respectively. I would not say it would be entirely of gemstone, unless it's only a small fragment, (100's of meters in diameter, maybe a few kilometers.)

To have a bright, not so dense moon, the best option is a icy moon. If it's in an eccentric orbit, there could be gravitational friction going on, causing cryovolcanism, replenishing the surface with fresh white "snow". Otherwise it will darken over time due to dust accumulation and cosmic radiation bombardment.

Comment: I know I'm asking a lot here, but could you extrapolate on the effects of a host planet if there were an icy Moon? You mention an eccentric orbit and I just wonder if the cryovolcanism would directly impact it's planet when it's in the closer stage of orbit. I'm assuming yes since the term "cryovolcanism" implies a pretty volatile situation. Though I'm thinking I may have to shirk a lot of real science and just say it's glass/translucent mineral "gems" in lattice formation because im pretty far in to change now... I do have two moons so maybe at least one of them can be realistic (lol)

Comment: I would assume your planet to be fairly massive, and if the moon is made mostly of water ice, then it would have ~1/5 the density of our moon, so for a relatively same size moon, you would have 1/5 the mass, and thus the planet would have a far greater effect on the moon than moon on the planet. However, there would be some effect. Normally, such a low mass moon would not effect the tides very much, but during its closest approach, the shift in tides would be noticeable. This would occur over 100's of millions of years, so life would adapt and it would not be seen as out of place.